# Prove that $x^2+x+2$ is maximal ideal in $F_3[x]$ ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Prove that $x^2+x+2$ is maximal ideal in $F_3[x]$ ring.

I think of using the theorem that $B$ is maximal ideal in $A$ if $A/B$ is field. Particularly in this case we need to prove that $F_3[x]/(x^2+x+2)$ is field. Could you please help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just verify that the polynomial does not have a root. If it was not maximal, it would have had a divisor of degree $1$, hence a root.

Comment: So, if we prove that x^2+x+2 is irreducible, then we are done?

Comment: Yes, irreducible will implies maximal in PID.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

The quadratic's discriminant is $\;\Delta=1-4\cdot2=-7=2\pmod3\;$ . Now check that $\;2\;$ is a *non-quadratic residue* modulo $\;3\;$ .