# Prove that the ideal $(x^2 + x+2)$ is maximal in $F_3[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, ideals

Prove that $(x^2 + x+2)$ ideal is a maximal ideal in $F_3[x]$ ring.

I know the theorem about factor rings and fields

> B ideal from A ring is maximal iff A/B factor-ring is a field

How can I use the theorem here?

Comment: Any particular reason you want to use that theorem?

Comment: I stacked there that, if $F_3[x]/(x^2+x+2)$ is a field, from theorem the ideal will be the maximal

Comment: No particular reasons

Comment: What do you know about irreducible polynomials?

Comment: The polynomial  has no root in $F_3$. So, firstly ask yourself why this implies irreducibility. ( irreducibility in finite filed an infinite field.) Secondly, you can look quotient ring with ideal generated by irreducible polynomial.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that $x^2+x+2$ is maximal ideal in $F_3[x]$ ring.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2578188/prove-that-x2x2-is-maximal-ideal-in-f-3x-ring)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $F$ is a field then a non-zero polynomial $f(x) \in F[x]$ is irreducible if and only if the ideal $(f)$ is prime if and only if the ideal $(f)$ is maximal. All you need to do is show that $x^2 + x + 2$ is irreducible. This is easy because all the possible factors are linear.